# Guassian Elimination with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I am struggling with Gaussian elimination with matrices. I need to bring the following matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&-1&2&1 & 2\\  
2&-3&2&0 & 3\\
-1&1&2&3 & 6\\
-3&2&0&3 & 9\\
\end{array}\right]$$

The matrix after the = sign is supposed to be augmented wth the first matrix but I as unable to do the proper formatting.

I know the final answer is

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-1  
\\0&1&0&0
\\0&0&1&1
\\0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-5\\-3\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}$

The question asked if the columns of A are linearly independent. I am looking for some help with walking through the steps of reduction and whether or not this matrix needs to be in reduced row echelon form or just row echelon form. I know to bring this to row echelon form you can only swap rows, add/subtract rows, and multiply rows by scalars, or add/subtract rows when multiplied by scalers

Comment: just looking for some basic strategies for guassian elimination

Comment: @ Rodrigo de Azevedo thanks for the edit,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through elimination:
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & -1 & 2 & 1 & 2\\
 2 & -3 & 2 & 0 & 3\\
-1 &  1 & 2 & 3 & 6\\
-3 &  2 & 0 & 3 & 9
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & -1 &  2 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & -1 & -2 & -2 & -1 \\
 0 &  0 &  4 & 4 & 8 \\
 0 & -1 &  6 & 6 & 15
\end{array}\right]
&&\begin{aligned} R_2&\gets R_2-2R_1\\R_3&\gets R_3+R_1\\R_4&\gets R_4+3R_1\end{aligned}
\tag{1}\\[6px]&\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & -1 &  2 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 &  1 &  2 &  2 &  1 \\
 0 &  0 &  4 & 4 & 8 \\
 0 &  1 &  8 & 8 & 16
\end{array}\right]
&&\begin{aligned} R_2&\gets -R_2\\R_4&\gets R_4+R_2\end{aligned}
\tag{2}\\[6px]&\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & -1 &  2 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 &  1 &  2 &  2 &  1 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
&&\begin{aligned} R_3&\gets \tfrac{1}{4}R_3\\R_4&\gets R_4-8R_3\end{aligned}
\tag{3}\\[6px]&\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & -1 &  0 & -1 & -2 \\
 0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  -3 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
&&\begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2-2R_3\\R_1&\gets R_1-2R_3\end{aligned}
\tag{4}\\[6px]&\to
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 &  0 &  0 & -1 & -5 \\
 0 &  1 &  0 &  0 &  -3 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
&&R_1\gets R_1+R_2
\tag{5}
\end{align}

Already after step $(3)$ you can conclude that the columns of the matrix $A$ are linearly dependent, because you get a null row in a row echelon form (just consider the first four columns); the fact that you get a full null row in the augmented matrix tells you that the linear system is solvable, because the last column cannot contain a leading $1$.

Steps $(4)$ and $(5)$ are *backwards elimination*, that lead to the *reduced row echelon form*, very useful to easily express all solutions.

Indeed, if we denote by $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ the unknowns, we see that $x_4$ is *free* and the equations read
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1-x_4=-5 \\[4px]
x_2 = -3 \\[4px]
x_3+x_4=2
\end{cases}
$$
so the generic solution is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-5+h\\
-3\\
2-h\\
h
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The advantage to go into this order for elimination is that it makes it possible to write the $LU$ decomposition of the matrix $A$. I use to denote the elementary operations we have performed up to step $(3)$ as
$$
E_{21}(-2),\quad
E_{31}(1),\quad
E_{41}(3),\quad
E_2(-1),\quad
E_{42}(1),\quad
E_3(\tfrac{1}{4}),\quad
E_{43}(-8)
$$
and this allows to write
$$
L=E_{21}(2)E_{31}(-1)E_{41}(-3)E_2(-1)E_{42}(-1)E_3(4)E_{43}(8)
=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 &  0 & 4 & 0 \\
-3 & -1 & 8 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
U=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -1 &  2 & 1 \\
 0 &  1 &  2 &  2 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 & 1 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You can check that $A=LU$.

Comment: @ egreg thanks a lot for your time, you ad a typo in your system of equations x1 - x4 = -5 not 5, also step 4 and 5 is this trying to get a 0 in row 1 column 2 and 3? if so why not get one for column 4?

Comment: @javahelper123 Thanks for pointing up the typo. In steps 4 and 5 we use each leading 1 to get zeros above it, which is what the reduced row echelon form should look like. There is no leading 1 in column 4.

Comment: @ egreg okay so if a leading 1 has a number above it then I should get rid of that number above, and if it fdoesnt have a number above then that's fine, also if there is no leading 1 in a row and it has all 0s then I can not reduce anything above?

Comment: and also does it have to be directly above?

Comment: @javahelper123 In step 4 we use the leading 1 in column 3 to get rid of the nonzero coefficients in column 3 above the leading 1 (there are zeros below because we already have a row echelon form).

Comment: @ egreg thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Call the rows $r_1 \ldots r_4$.. After the following 8 operations you arrive at your answer:
$$r_4 \leftarrow r_4 - 3r_3$$
$$r_3 \leftarrow r_3 + r_1$$
$$r_2 \leftarrow r_2 - 2r_1$$
$$r_4 \leftarrow r_4 - r_2$$
$$r_4 \leftarrow r_4 + r_3$$
$$r_2 \leftarrow 2r_2 + r_3$$
$$r_1 \leftarrow 2r_1 - r_2$$
$$r_1 \leftarrow r_1 - r_3$$